# how to get EE3 Grid data filled out on frontend

Tags: ee3, grid

I have a grid with 4 columns that i'm trying to get before they click submit.  Each time they add a row (non member player) in this grid I need to grab that rows data and use it with PHP to show information based off their gender and expected ranking.

When I inspect the input box in dev tools, it doesn't seem to spit out that data so i'm having trouble triggering as I don't know how it stores that data.  I would've thought it would've changed the "value" of that input.  A columns input looks something like this after I enter "testname":

```
<input type="text" name="non_member_players[rows][new_row_1][col_id_9]" value="" dir="ltr" field_content_type="all" maxlength="256">
```

Comment: Do I have to use the hooks or something?

Comment: A little more clarity might help. Where is this happening: Front end Channel Form, or backend in the control panel? And you want to work with grid data before it's submitted (on a live form) or after it's already in the database?

Comment: I have a form inside a channel form tag.... as you fill out data I'm doing some ajax work based on data you enter and I need to grab the grid data to do ajax as you fill in the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think I found it.  Despite the dev tools not showing the actual value on the input that was filled in, i was able to grab data based off the name attr and it spits out the filled in data still.

```
$('input[name="non_member_players[rows][new_row_1][col_id_9]"]').val();
```